# Use WebClient to POST query and download file

Tags: c#, .net, rest, webclient

Can I post data to a URI and download a file in a single `WebClient` request?

`TL;DR`

I'm using a class extending `WebClient` to contact our PHP API and download a file. The class adds a `CookieContainer` to the `WebClient` to enable a PHP session.

1. `WebClient.UploadValues()` posts a `NameValueCollection` query to the server to authenticate the following request.
2. `WebClient.DownloadFile()` downloads the file.

This is the only part of the API that's not very RESTful and I'd prefer to move this into a single stateless query.

I can use `WebClient.QueryString` to manually set the `NameValueCollection` query string before calling `DownloadFile()` but that method uses the GET method, and the API is expecting POST data.

Can the method be set to POST before calling `DownloadFile()` ? Is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I realized (*doh*).

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues(url, data);
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, result);
}
```

`UploadValues()` sends POST data.  The returned byte[] array will be the file.